# How to decrease two relation to one relation in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `ContractTable` with three column like this

```
ContractID |  CompanyID | ContractorID
-----------+------------+----------
     2     |    37725   |    37730
```

this table has relation with this view `ViewNameList` :

```
    ID     |  CompanyTitle
-----------+--------------
 37725     |      X  
 37730     |      Y
```

I don't want to get result with two join. Is there any way to get result like  follow, with one relation?

```
ContractID |  CompanyID | ContractorID
-----------+------------+----------
     2     |      X     |     Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` the view twice

```
select y.ContractID,v1.CompanyTitle as CompanyID,v2.CompanyTitle as ContractorID
from yourtable y
Left join view  v1 on y.CompanyID  = v1.ID     
Left join view  v2 on y.ContractorID = v2.ID
```

If you dont want to join twice then try this

```
SELECT y.ContractID,
       Max(CASE WHEN y.CompanyID = v.ID THEN v.CompanyTitle END) AS CompanyID,
       Max(CASE WHEN y.ContractorID = v.ID THEN v.CompanyTitle END) AS ContractorID
FROM   yourtable y
       JOIN [view] v
         ON v.ID IN ( y.CompanyID, y.ContractorID )
GROUP  BY y.ContractID
```

Comment: Is there any way to converted to LINQ syntax?

Comment: @SasanKarimi - I don't know `LINQ`

Answer (score 0):

If join is bothering you, the you could do that without any joins. ie:

```
SELECT t1.ContractID ,
       (SELECT CompanyTitle FROM ViewNameList t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.CompanyID) CompanyID,
       (SELECT CompanyTitle FROM ViewNameList t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ContractorID) ContractorID
       FROM ContractTable t1;
```

And of course, doing this in Linq is much easier:

```
var contracts = from c in db.Contracts
                select new {
                   ContractID   = c.ContractID,
                   CompanyID    = c.Company.CompanyTitle,
                   ContractorID = c.Contractor.CompanyTitle
                };
```